# How to get Capital letters in the first letter i entered

Tags: customization, configuration

If i entered "name" in my text box while it saved it must be saved like "Name"

Capital letters in the first letter of Alphabet

It must not show any error messages it must directly save

Answer (score 7):

Use workflow + field update
under field update writ formulae UPPER(LEFT(FirstName, 1))

Comment: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hNUHAA2

Answer (score 3):

From the docs: 
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_String_capitalize.htm

```
String s = 'hello maximillian';

String s2 = s.capitalize();

System.assertEquals('Hello maximillian',s2);
```

Comment: You'll want to do this in a 'before insert/update' trigger... nasusnunu, can you add code to show that?

Comment: hi how can i do it by using workflows can anyone say

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below app from AppExchange, its free

[Capitalize](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5YhNEAV)